# remove a file with dashes from git

Tags: git, git-merge

During a git merge conflict I created a file named 'e --abort'

my attempt to remove the file:

> $ rm ./e --abort

and get this:

> rm: unrecognized option `--abort'

also tried:

> $ git rm -- e --abort

and got:

> fatal: pathspec 'e' did not match any files

because the dashes are not at the beginning this did not work for me

Comment: You might have to escape it like `$ git rm e\ --abort` not sure you should escape the `-`, but if so: `$ git rm e\ \-\-abort` I use MACOSX and thats the way I use to escape whitespace characters.

Comment: The problem here is the space more than the dashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try escaping the space in the file name: `rm ./e\ --abort`

Answer (score 2):

Single quote the file name:

```
rm 'e --abort'
```

Also, if your shell does auto escaping when you tab complete you can usually do

```
rm e<tab> => rm e\ --abort
```